# Chart draws line from first to last point

Tags: c#, charts

My program connects to a server which sends updates for a chart in json-format.

The first received update after the connection is established contains all available points for the chart, like this:

```
{"data":[[1484224017,3000],[1484224077,3020],...]}
```

After the first update is received, the server will send a new data-point every 60 seconds. The format of the json-message is the same, only that it contains a single value:

```
{"data":[[1484225012,3018]]}
```

The data is added to the chart like this:

```
foreach (var entry in json["data"])
{
    this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(this.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(entry[0].ToObject<double>()), entry[1].ToObject<double>());
}

this.chart1.Refresh();
```

After the first update, the chart looks fine:

[image]

However, after the first update is received, the chart draws a line from the first point to the last, newly added point:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: @jstreet It is cleared, only the single point is added.

Comment: @jstreet Hmm, I was pretty sure that I cleared it. I will have a look at it later and report back!

Comment: From the looks it seems that the new point has an x-value that is the same at the 1st one. Your example data don't but what about the real data??

Comment: @TaW i checked that already, it doesn't have the same X-Value. Also, if I restart the program the chart is shown correctly again until the next update happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have a chart with dynamically recreated series. Points was added by Points.AddXY() method. My solution was to clear all series points before recreate series. 
Something like that:

```
foreach (Series seriesItem in chartObject.Series)
{
   seriesItem.Points.Clear();
}

chartObjectDynamic.Series.Clear();
```